# how to add `.ToList()` method into Typescript `Array<T>` class?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

how to add `.ToList()` method into Typescript's `Array<T>` class. I am expecting the following result finally.

```
let nums:List<number> = [1,2,3,5,6].ToList();
let strs:List<string> = ["abc", "cdf", "efg"].ToList();
```

please share if any example git repo is available.

I am getting the following error.

[image]

without exporting interface i am getting the following error

[image]

Comment: what is the List interface? Something custom in your code?

Comment: yes.. List<T>  is my own implementation..

Comment: Why are Array and List red in your screenshots?

Comment: I feel like you have a syntax error in the file pripr to these lines

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. Could you show us the whole file?

Comment: You are missing the type parameter for List, T.  It says you have conflicting types.

Comment: @ArcSine it should infer the type parameter from `this`. It does infer it in my tests.

Comment: Did you install tsc via node `npm -g install tsc`? If so, could you check which version visual studio uses?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5995

Comment: I believe the type T is lost given the way the prototype is handled.  It might be a bug in typescript, but I believe I've encountered this before.

Comment: @ArcSine That's possible, but the exact same code compiles in the playground and on my visual studio too. strange.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the Javascript way, by adding that function to the **Array.prototype**. However if you want type safety you will have to do a little bit of type assertions.

Add the function to the Array prototype:

```js
(<any>Array.prototype).ToList = function() {
    return this.join(",");
}
```

TypeScript allows you to extend interfaces by redeclaring them and adding your own functions:

```js
interface Array<T> {
    ToList: () => string
}
```

Assert that the array you want to call ToList on is the interface type:

```js
let a = [1,2,3,5,6].ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The interface for Array is extensible as all interfaces in typescript are extensible. A quick example:

list.d.ts:

```
interface Array<T> {
  ToList():List;
}
```

list.ts:

```
/// <reference "./list.d.ts" />  
Array.prototype.ToList = function() {
  return this.toString();
}
```

Using it:

```
let arr = [1,2,3]
let list = arr.ToList();
```

Comment: I did the same. but getting error. I attached the screenshot FYR.

Comment: What version of typescript are you working with?  I tested the above in the [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and it compiled properly.

Comment: Ahh I see the problem, the error you are getting is due to the export.  If you want to export the interface, you need to define a separate .d.ts file and include that.

Comment: Updated the example to show the breakdown of the separate files usually seen when working with a custom .d.ts file.

Comment: `list.d.ts` shows the error  `Cannot find name 'List'`

Answer (score 0):

Just do not `export` the interface and your code will compile without errors.

```
class List<T> {
    constructor(items: T[]) {}
}

interface Array<T> {
    ToList():List<T>;
}

Array.prototype.ToList = function() {
    return new List(this);
};
```

Try it on the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html)

**EDIT #1**

It looks like exporting literally anything from the module breaks the compilation, and causes OP's error. I submitted an issue to Microsoft. See: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8278

**EDIT #2**

Okay, so it turned out that adding an export statement to the above example (literally exporting anything) causes OP's error. The guys at Microsoft answered our issue, turns out we did not specify the type information of the Array interface the right way. So here is how to do it:

```
class List<T> {
    constructor(items: T[]) {}
}

declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        ToList():List<T>;
    }
}

Array.prototype.ToList = function() {
    return new List(this);
};

export default List;
```

Comment: getting error because of `export` at front of the `class` in my code. Without `export` I can't use that class in another `ts` file.

Comment: @NatarajanGanapathi That looks like a bug in typescript. I submitted an issue (see my update), will see how it should work.

Answer (score 0):

finally I got the answer.

```
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        ToList(): List<T>;
    }
}

Array.prototype.ToList = function() {
    return new List(this);
}`

export class List<T> {
    constructor(private array: T[] = []) {}

     public Add(item: T): List<T> {
        this.array.push(item);
        return this.array.ToList();
    }
}
```